# How can I make IIS 7.5 play flash video

Tags: video, iis-7.5

I created an application inside IIS 7.5 and inside that application a virtual directory is created. I have kept a flash video file in that to play locally (via browser).

It works fine in IIS 5.0 (on a xp). However, on IIS 7.5, it does not run, the video gets stuck in the beginning.

The video works fine when I double click on the html file from the windows explorer.

Any ideas what settings I should change or how to debug this? Event viewer does not show anything. I gave full permission to the video folder.

OS is windows server 2008 R2

Thanks

Comment: Looks like the flash is starting but the video is not playing. When I copy the folder to an external website it works fine! this got to be some settings in the IIS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure that IIS 7.5 is setup to serve the MIME types for the .swf and .flv extensions, as well as anything else that needs to be served, even for static content. Otherwise IIS will 404 because it doesn't know how to serve them. In your website, select MIME Types and add one for .swf as `application/x-shockwave-flash` and .flv as `video/x-flv`.

EDIT: You may need to add one for .mp4, which is `video/mp4`. IIS 7.5 should have ones for .flv and .swf already, but .mp4 is a common case where it does not.

Comment: That does not seem to be the case. I checked the mime types and they are there as you suggested. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that MP4 is likely your culprit from your additional comment; you maybe have to restart the IIS service as well. If that still doesn't fix it, what happens when you directly browse to the MP4 video? A 404 is almost always a severe permission issue or a MIME issue.

Comment: somehow mp4 file had a small lock on the icon. Adding everyone permission to the mp4 file solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

For Clear understanding of others.

*Let me put it step by step*

1)Choose the **website** to configure in IIS

2)Right click Choose **Properties**

3)Choose **HTTP Headers Tab**

4)Choose **File Types** under the **MIME Map** section

5)Choose **New Type** type **.flv** as the extension and **video/x-flv** or **flv-application/octet-stream** as the mime type and choose **OK**.

if still no change then restart iis.