# Flash Player is not installed Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash

I am working on a project which in one of its page , I use Adobe Flash Player component. When i publish it on the server the page has not any issue , but when I want to open that page on the local IIS , it gives me an error that Adobe Flash Player is not installed.

How weird is this.
is there anybody out there to help me on this ?

The site has been written in Asp.Net MVC 5
Local IIS : Version 10 (windows 10)
Server IIS : version 10 (Windows Server 2015)
Browser : All browser
Flash player for Chrome is installed

**UPDATE** : I`ve set SWF and FLV MIME type in local IIS too

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your MIME types correctly in IIS.

See:

[How can I make IIS 7.5 play flash video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111384/how-can-i-make-iis-7-5-play-flash-video)

Comment: I checked that before , it didint fix my issue